# What is the literal translation of Proverbs 14:20?

Tags: greek, proverbs

> φίλοι μισήσουσιν φίλους πτωχούς φίλοι δὲ πλουσίων πολλοί
>   
>   phíloi misḗsousin phílous ptōkhoús phíloi dè plousíōn polloí.
>   
>   people hate people poor people not rich many
>   
>   "The poor is disliked even by his neighbor, but the rich has many friends."

My literal rough translation (not knowing greek) is basically "people hate people poor people not rich many". How do they get the final sentence out of the greek?

Comment: The final translation, the one in quotes - where is that from?

Comment: That's not a rough translation, that's a list of root lexemes that completely ignores all morphology. You need to account for the morphology (and syntax, though it's often less important for Greek than for English) to produce even a rough translation.

Comment: biblical hermeneutics SE would probably be a better place to ask this question

Answer (score 2):

You have quoted a Greek version

The Hebrew text of Prov 14:20 is:

> גַּם־לְ֭רֵעֵהוּ יִשָּׂ֣נֵא רָ֑שׁ וְאֹהֲבֵ֖י עָשִׁ֣יר רַבִּֽים׃

This is well translated by several versions as:

- YLT: Even of his neighbour is the poor hated, And those loving the rich are many.
- NASB: The poor is hated even by his neighbor, But those who love the rich are many.
- ESV: The poor is disliked even by his neighbor, but the rich has many friends.
- BSB: The poor man is hated even by his neighbor, but many are those who love the rich.

The LXX text of Prov 14:20 is:

> φίλοι μισήσουσιν φίλους πτωχούς, φίλοι δὲ πλουσίων πολλοί.

This could be well translated as:

Friends will hate poor friends; but the friends of the rich are many.